# Is it possible to use phpMyAdmin to connect to a remote host, but keep the configuration db on the local host

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have search the internet and so far none of what I could find 100% relates to my issue

I am looking to deploy a phpMyAdmin (PMA) server in our company for devs to access the various DB's with. I would however prefer keeping the PMA extra functionality on the local PMA server.

I have installed PMA 4.4.15.10 from the CentOS repo's on CentOS 7.

I have setup PMA's config.inc.php to allow for connections to the remote DB hosts and I am able to login.

I have enabled and configured extra functionality for localhost (pma1), but I cannot get it to work for the remote hosts.

My current config.inc.php looks like (some obfuscation for security reasons)

```
<?php
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '***';

$cfg['DisplayServersList'] = TRUE;
$cfg['ZeroConf'] = TRUE;
$i = 0;

$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost']   = 'localhost';                         
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']   = '***';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']   = '***';
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'DB1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']       = 'DB1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost']   = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb']         = 'phpmyadmin_db1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']   = '***';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']   = '***';
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'DB2';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']       = 'DB2';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost']   = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb']         = 'phpmyadmin_db2';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']   = '***';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']   = '***';
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'DB3';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']       = 'DB3';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost']   = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb']         = 'phpmyadmin_db3';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']   = '***';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']   = '***';
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'DB4';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']       = 'DB4';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost']   = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb']         = 'phpmyadmin_db4';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']   = '***';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']   = '***';

$cfg['UploadDir'] = '/var/lib/phpMyAdmin/upload';
$cfg['SaveDir']   = '/var/lib/phpMyAdmin/save';

$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = FALSE;
?>
```

And on the PMA server (localhost) I created these databases to hold the configs

```
phpmyadmin
phpmyadmin_db1
phpmyadmin_db2
phpmyadmin_db3
phpmyadmin_db4
```

If I log into db1, I get the following error

```
The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why. 
  Or alternately go to 'Operations' tab of any database to set it up there.
```

And following the link "Find out why"
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] ...    OK
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] ... not OK
    General relation features: Disabled

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] ...   not OK
Display Features: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] ... not OK
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] ...    not OK
Designer and creation of PDFs: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] ...  not OK
Displaying Column Comments: Disabled
Browser transformation: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] ...    not OK
Bookmarked SQL query: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] ...  not OK
SQL history: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] ...   not OK
Persistent recently used tables: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] ... not OK
Persistent favorite tables: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] ...    not OK
Persistent tables' UI preferences: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] ... not OK
Tracking: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] ...   not OK
User preferences: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] ...    not OK
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] ...   not OK
Configurable menus: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] ... not OK
Hide/show navigation items: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] ...    not OK
Saving Query-By-Example searches: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] ...  not OK
Managing Central list of columns: Disabled
```

However the relevant tables does exsist in PMA1:phpmyadmin_db1

```
pma__bookmark
pma__central_columns
pma__column_info
pma__favorite
pma__history
pma__navigationhiding
pma__pdf_pages
pma__recent
pma__relation
pma__savedsearches
pma__table_coords
pma__table_info
pma__table_uiprefs
pma__tracking
pma__userconfig
pma__usergroups
pma__users
```

Which tells me it is not picking up the tables from the controlhost.

I have tried changing the controlhost to the hostname of the PMA server, not joy.

Also googling I cant seem to determine if this is a possibility or not, so any pointers or config changes would be appreciated.

Kind regards